# Where is the bridge of Host-only network in VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

When I configure a Host-only network in VirtualBox, and connect a VM to it, I can see that my host has a new interface called "vboxnet0":

```bsh
9: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.1/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global vboxnet0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

My VM has an interface:

[image: VM network]

According to an article on https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/ (Host-only section), the Host-only mode works in a way that my host's adapter and VM adapter are connected via a virtual switch.
Where is that switch? I thought I'd see a bridge interface on my host representing that. However, all I see is "vboxnet0" which seems to represent an adapter on my host for this network.

Answer (score 0):

The switch is virtual. Imagine two hosts with a network card each, both connected to a physical (unmanaged) switch. What you have is a virtual i.e. software) version of that.

Comment: Right. Isn’t that what „bridge” link type represents? I.e., a bridge network created by Docker (docker0) may be seen when I invoke ‘ip link show’ on my host. I’d expect to see the bridge/switch created by VirtualBox the same way

Comment: Well, you don't "see" a physical switch connected to two Ethernet cards either, just the interfaces on either end.

Comment: Myreen Yes, however I wonder what is the difference here. How is the Docker's docker0 bridge different from VirtualBox's bridge. Is it just that VirtualBox team implemented the bridge functionality inside of the VirtualBox "binary", and it just doesn't use the Linux's built-in bridge implementation?